# MS OneNote on Mac: how to print landscape?

Tags: mac, pdf, printing, microsoft-onenote, handwriting

I would love to print a page of a notebook in landscape, as when I write in it with iPad pen it always breaks the page when I export it as PDF or print it. Do you guys know how to do so?

In general, I like OneNote for preparing speeches or a presentation outline that I then export and send to my collaborator to actually produce slides. But every time it is a mess to export and send a well formatted pdf. Do you have other better suggestions?

Comment: From the description, I am unable to imagine how the page content is broken. Did you check page printing options in *File* > *Print* > *Print Preview* menu? Just [edit] your question to add necessary details.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it's not a simple "select landscape" solution, which I find ridiculous.

However, you sort of "trick" it into landscape by:

- Widening the content area. Typically it will start wrapping a portrait width, but you can grab the border of the content box and drag it wider.
- Then in print settings, select "2 Pages per Sheet" in the Layout section.

IMPORTANT: Unfortunately, this leaves a blank line down your content, where the 2 portrait sheets are side by side to make the one landscape

The other alternative of course is to just copy and paste into MS Word and just print in landscape from there.